# Saving ZIP file attachments and reading them in Git Bash

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, zip

I lost a lot of time today without finding any solution to what seems a simple problem on Windows 7.

#### Problem description

I received a Zip file attachment in Microsoft Outlook, and I want to save it and then unzip it or otherwise access the files in it in [git bash](https://gitforwindows.org).

Now, having saved the Zip file, I can see it fine in Windows Explorer, where it is listed as a "Compressed (zipped) folder".

But, if I try to view it from git bash, say if I use the `ls -a` command, I can't see it. Likewise, if I try to find it using the Unix `find` command, I can't find it.

However, if I create a new Zip file using 7-zip, everything is fine. I can see it in Windows Explorer (and the file type is still the same, "Compressed (zipped) folder"), and I can also see it from git bash (where I just see a file with a .zip extension).

Perhaps Microsoft Outlook is doing something special when it saves Zip file attachments?

#### Experiment

To test this if this is the case, I did the following steps.

1. Using 7-zip, I created a Zip file by zipping up a directory that I could see in git bash. For reference, this file was in ~/Documents.
2. In Windows explorer, the Zip "folder" created (because Windows Explorer seems to see all Zip files as "folders") has these properties:

[image]

Advanced:

[image]

And from git bash, using the Linux-like tools, I see:

```
$ ls -l ~/Documents/CIMS.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 redacted 1049089 156383 Sep 6 15:30 /c/Users/redacted/Documents/CIMS.zip
```

and

```
$ stat ~/Documents/CIMS.zip
File: /c/Users/redacted/Documents/CIMS.zip
Size: 156383 Blocks: 156 IO Block: 65536 regular file
Device: 7c8023c0h/2088772544d Inode: 2251799813896974 Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid: (redacted/redacted) Gid: (redacted/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2018-09-06 15:30:21.838707400 +1000
Modify: 2018-09-06 15:30:21.897707400 +1000
Change: 2018-09-06 15:30:21.899707400 +1000
Birth: 2018-09-06 15:30:21.838707400 +1000
```

3. Next, I emailed the file to myself, and then I saved the one I received from myself in ~/Desktop.
4. I checked from git bash, and I can not see that file saved on my desktop:

   $ ls -a ~/Desktop/
   ./    ../   desktop.ini   get-pip.py*   'Microsoft Outlook 2010.lnk'*

However, from Windows Explorer, the properties of the Zip file are identical to the original copy in ~/Documents:

[image]

and

[image]

#### Question

Apparently, Outlook is doing something to these files when it saves them. Is there any convenient way to save these files just as normal Zip files?

Comment: Are you in the same folder? Why are you using the -l argument? LS just shows the files in a directory. If you're not in the same directory it isn't Window's fault that LS won't see the folders. Please EDIT your question to add relevant information so that we can better tell what the actual problem is.

Comment: Also, when you receive .zip files from sources other than email/Outlook do you have the same problem? And "Compressed (zipped) folder" is simply the description of the file type based on the file extension and I don't know that it is relevant to the problem.

Comment: I am certainly in the right directory. I believe that Compressed (zipped) folder is relevant here, since that's the only file type that causes this observed behaviour. The `-l` option reveals additional information about files, but I suppose you are right that it isn't relevant here. I have edited that out.

Comment: To your second point, I will do a test where I create a zip file myself using the zip command. Good idea, thanks.

Comment: @music2myear updated. Your suggestion was helpful. See my updates to the question. It appears to be an Outlook-related issue.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Does this issue occur to all .zip attachments you received in Outlook? Can you unzip the downloaded attachment without using Git Bash? 
It is also suggested to test in webmail to see the result.

Comment: The file you created with 7zip that Bash sees: Create an email to yourself and attach the zip file to it. Then save THAT file and see if you experience the same symptoms.

Comment: See my updates to the question.